# How to make one input that is given to 2 Scripts and how to run a script in a script Python

Tags: python, subprocess, call

So I want to make an input into a script1. Script1 then continues do to stuff with the input and then at a certain elif statement after checking some cases script1 calls a script2 which continues to check something with the input that i gave to script1. After checking something script2 calls itself again and again until a certain statement is true.
So my question is, is there a way to give a input via `input` to both of the scripts at once or like parse it to the second script and is there a way to start script2 from script1 and then get script2 to call itself ?

Comment: Are you familiar with how to define a function in one file and import it into another?

Comment: not completely i would like an example if you could state one

Answer (score 1):

It would be something like that:

script1:

```
from script2 import *

input = input("your input")

def your_verifications(input):
    if your_condition:
        // thing you want to do
    elif another_condition:
        // where you want to call script 2
        script2_verifications(input)


your_verifications(input)
```

script2 (in a different file but in the same folder than script1)

```
def script2_verifications(input):
    while the_statement_you_want_to_be_true != True:
        // things you want to do
```

I hope I answered your question and that I didn't make any mistake

Comment: Thats quite nearly what I wanted thanks. But there is one question. I have tried  to implement it with the difference of first running script1 then in the if Statement called the function from Script2 and in Script2 there is another if Statement and if that is treu it runs itself again so `if condition: script2_verifications(input)`. It does work for some time but then it kinda stops even tho it should Start again is there like a limit you can call a function in itself?

Comment: You want to run the function again if a statement is True ? Or do you want to do a recursive function ?